# How to approximate a trigonometric to make less computation complexity

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity

I having a trigonometric function such as
$$ p_2(s) =
\begin{cases}
\frac {1}{(2 \pi)^2}(1-\cos (2 \pi s)),  & \text{if $s \le1$ } \\
\frac {1}{2 }(s-1)^2,  & \text{if $s >1$ }
\end{cases}$$
The function  has two minimum points $s =1$ and $s= 0$. The figure of the above function such as
[image]

However, the computational time is more expensive. To reduce it, one guy proposed a approximate function using polynomial such as
$$ p_2(s) =
\begin{cases}
\frac {1}{2}s^2(s-1)^2+\frac {1}{2}s^3(s-1)^3,  & \text{if $s \le1$ } \\
\frac {1}{2 }(s-1)^2,  & \text{if $s >1$ }
\end{cases}$$

He said that his method is trigonometric representation because he used polynomial. **Is it right?** Could you suggest to me other representation that has similar properties of above function. Thanks

Comment: You should have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem. Of course you need to be careful with approximation, for the evaluation of error is very important to assess...

Comment: Do you have any idea to approximate  a trigonometric  to polynomial function such as my question? I don't know why he can approximate a trigonometric  by a polynomial

Comment: Have a look at Bernstein polynomials. The fact is that the expression can be reduced to $\alpha \sin^2(\pi s)$, which is clearly symmetrical with $s=0.5$ as the axis fo symmetry.